# Spring Boot shutting down Automatically on AWS EC2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, shutdown

I have 2 Spring boot webflux based applications running on EC2. One on port 8082 and other on 8083. I manage the release on EC2 via bamboo.
For a couple of weeks now, I have been seeing the 8083 app shutting down by itself, a graceful shutdown. I do not see any process crashes from monitoring tools like dynatrace.
I don’t see any out of Memory errors as well. Both the apps are started by bamboo via nohup java command. Only point that I observe is when the 8083 app goes down there is spike in the network traffic shown by dynatrace. App on 8082 runs without any issues so far. Could you pls suggest on specific pointer on this.

Comment: please post logs and how the service is started etc. There is way too little information to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the root cause. There seemed to be a conflict between the  release scripts of applications running on 8082 and 8083. Releasing one was affecting the other. Since it was a Linux server and the release script was killing the process ids as part of the release this was happening.